# Difference between [print "Total Fruits %d" % fruits.fruitsCount ] and [print "Total Fruits ",fruits.fruitsCount]

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python,

```
print "Total Fruits %d" % fruits.fruitsCount
print "Total Fruits ",fruits.fruitsCount
```

Output are same in both scenarios. What is the difference between both the statement? Is one better than the other?

Comment: one more space will be printed for the second one

Comment: BTW both statements are invalid in Python 3.x and second one print _two_ spaces between word 'Fruits' and their count (because space is also a separator).

Comment: First one checks the type via format, second does not.

Answer (score 3):

```
print "Total Fruits %d" % fruits.fruitsCount
```

This uses string formatting to first create a single string which is then printed.

```
print "Total Fruits ",fruits.fruitsCount
```

This one uses the print statement’s capabilities to print multiple values at once. `print` will just concat all values it gets; for everything that is not a string, it will call `str()` on the value. Note that the print statement will automatically add a space between each argument, so your output will have two spaces between “Fruits” and the count. To get the same output as above, remove the trailing space in `"Total Fruits"`.

As for one being better than the other, it depends. The `print` statement alone is a lot simpler if you just want to output stuff. But if you need more control over how the output is formatted, you will end up using a format string. This is especially true if you want to embedded values within the string. For example this isn’t possible using the `print` statement alone (because of the implicit spaces):

```
print "Fruits in parentheses (%d)" % fruits.fruitsCount
```

You can also use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which is the new way to use format strings:

```
print "Fruits in parentheses ({})".format(fruits.fruitsCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Different operator are used when you  formating your string in python**

**%c**  character

**%s**  string conversion via str() prior to formatting

**%i**  signed decimal integer

**%d**  signed decimal integer

**%u**  unsigned decimal integer

**%o**  octal integer

**%x**  hexadecimal integer (lowercase letters)

**%X**  hexadecimal integer (UPPERcase letters)

**%e**  exponential notation (with lowercase 'e')

**%E**  exponential notation (with UPPERcase 'E')

**%f**  floating point real number

**%g**  the shorter of %f and %e

**%G**  the shorter of %f and %E

the above different string formating operator is used when you want to append the string in to the particular variable value.

**For Example :**

print "My name is %s and weight is %d kg!" % ('chaitanya', 21)

hear string with formating with string variable and integer variable on your  original string.

I hope this should helpful for you ..)